# Correct URL syntax to be given for admin grid custom buttons

Tags: magento2.4

I am using Magento version 2.4 and with a need to have a custom button in admin products listing, which would redirect users to a custom admin page. I created view/adminhtml/product_listing.xml with following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="new_button" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">odoo_sync_button</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sync stock with Odoo Manually</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">action-secondary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">odoo_sync/sync/index</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</listing>
```

**Can someone please let me know the correct syntax for attaching this URL to the button ?**

Button is rendered but on click , it redirects to the dashboard with the message 'Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page.'.

Same custom admin page is accessible via Admin menu. Please see etc/adminhtml/routes.xml & etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="odoosync" frontName="odoosync">
            <module name="Iwdat_StockManager172" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="mnu_odoo::manager" title="Odoo Sync" module="Iwdat_StockManager172" sortOrder="10" resource="Iwdat_StockManager172::manager"/>
        <add id="mnu_odoo_sync::manager" title="Odoo Sync Go" module="Iwdat_StockManager172" sortOrder="0" parent="mnu_odoo::manager"
                action="odoosync/sync" resource="Iwdat_StockManager172::manager"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Controller in Controller/Adminhtml/Sync folder

```
<?php
namespace Iwdat\StockManager172\Controller\Adminhtml\Sync;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku; 
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterfaceFactory;        
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceItemsSaveInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
.
.
.
}
```

Thanks and Best Regards

Indunil

Comment: Replace odoo_sync/sync/index with  odoosync/sync/index at product_listing.xml

Comment: @ZahidHussainMagento, Thanks a lot. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your **product_listing.xml** with below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="new_button" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">odoo_sync_button</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sync stock with Odoo Manually</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">action-secondary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">odoosync/sync/index</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</listing>
```

This will work for you.

Please let me know if you got any issue

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Can you please also let me know the reason for ommiting underscore .

Comment: Because of not matching route url.

Comment: @ZahidHussainMagento , ah simple as that :) . Thanks a lot.